# Parent of symbolic path

Tags: path, terminology, mediawiki

I am having trouble understanding [this manual](https://wiki.its.sfu.ca/math/skins/README) about the MediaWiki CMS.

> Please note that under POSIX systems (Linux...), parent of a symbolic path
> refers to the link source, NOT to the target! You should check the env
> variable MW_INSTALL_PATH in case the extension is not in the default location.

What did the author mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The meaning is that under UNIX systems, if you create a symbolic link like this:

```
ln -s [source]      [target]
ln -s /tmp/test/foo /tmp/test2/bar
```

the parent of `/tmp/test2/bar`, while actually being `/tmp/test2`, is technichally speaking `/tmp/test/`.

Disclaimer: Sometimes this behavior can actually affect you, but in 90% of the cases I've dealt with, this should not be of your concern (E.g. if you `cd /tmp/test2/bar` and then `cd ..` you will still be in `/tmp/test2`, not in `/tmp/test`).